# Oracle: Combining similar names together

Tags: sql, oracle, normalization

```
ItemNo  Name      Requested Qty
850045  MICHAEL         46  1045
850045  MICHAEL JACKSON 38  834
850045  LARRY SHEARIN   22  473
850045  Michael Jackson 11  233
850045  Larry           5   84
```

I have a table where Requester Name is not normalized. Michael and Michael Jack are the same person. Larry and Larry Shearin are also the same person. Is there a way to combine row data so that the Requested and Qty also sum up correctly? I was thinking there might be some sort of Oracle function or analytic that would do this...

```
ItemNo  Name      Requested Qty
850045  MICHAEL JACKSON 95  2112
850045  LARRY SHEARIN   27  557
```

Comment: Their ID should have been in that table instead, that way there would be no variation. You cannot be so sure it's one person that bears Michael all the time, it could refer to someone else... that is reality

Comment: We are looking into normalizing the data via loginid or first part of the e-mail address. Fortunately, the requester for a recurring item tend to be the same people so this becomes less of an issue. Thanks for your concern -- it is a valid one.

Answer (score 1):

There may be another way, but this should work using UPPER and matching any firstname (without spaces) to any fullname (with a space) -- if multiple full names match, you're results will be inaccurate.

```
SELECT T.ItemNo, 
  T.Name, 
  T.Requested + T2.Requested Requested,
  T.Qty + T2.Qty Qty
FROM (
    SELECT ItemNo, UPPER(Name) as Name, SUM(Requested) Requested, SUM(Qty) Qty
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Name LIKE '% %'
    GROUP BY ItemNo, UPPER(Name)
  ) T
  JOIN (
    SELECT ItemNo, UPPER(Name) as Name, SUM(Requested) Requested, SUM(Qty) Qty
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Name NOT LIKE '% %'
    GROUP BY ItemNo, UPPER(Name)
  ) T2 ON T.ItemNo = T2.ItemNo AND T.Name LIKE T2.Name||' %'
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2486e/4).

And here are the results:

```
ITEMNO  NAME            REQUESTED  QTY
850045  MICHAEL JACKSON 95         2112
850045  LARRY SHEARIN   27         557
```

I assume you're total (32) for Larry was mistaken above (22 + 5)?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could I use upper or lower function to make the names consistent case?

Comment: @SunWKim - yes, of course :) -- see edits -- long day and was thinking about another project.  Best of luck.

Comment: So, with this query what happens to those names that do not contain a space? Does the query exclude those records?

Comment: @SunWKim -- can you give an example?  Not sure I understand your question?  your question was about similar names, not identical ones?

Comment: I have a situation where if the requestor name used for that item is only JOHN, but no records with JOHN LAST, then JOHN is not included in the query set.